# how to ssh to home computer from outside

Tags: networking, ssh, home-networking, remote-access

I have ubuntu machine at my home where i have Time Warner internet connection. Sometimes I want to connect to my home computer when I'm outside but unable to.

What IP address should I ssh to? Do I have to install a new software?
On my ubuntu machine when I do 'ifconfig' it gives 192.168.1.112

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `192.168.1.*` is a local IP address. You need to subscribe to a dynamic [dns service](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=dynamic+dns+service) to find your external ip address

This allows you to ping something like `kumar.dyndns.com` and have it return your router's external address.

You need to configure your router settings to forward activity on the ssh port to your computer within your home network. This is called *port forwarding*.

---

Notably this exposes you to some risk. Consider using a non-default SSH port and using private-key-only authentication (rather than a password). If you do use a password you should look into the various packages that defend against bruteforce attacks

Comment: There is no need to subscribe to a service to discover your IP address. You can use one of the many web pages that tell you your IP. However, even if you know it, Time Warner can change it on you at any time and you can't easily know what it is without actually being at the computer. *This* is where the dynamic DNS server comes in - which also has a requirement (or maybe not, if you don't mind using the service's domain) of having your own domain name.